# if input equals string, do something... python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

Having trouble with the following code:

```
start_over = 1

question = input("Do you wish to try again? y/n: ")
if question == "y":
    start_over -= 1
else:
    raise SystemExit
```

If they enter `y`, it goes straight to the `else` condition.

**Solved, was using input instead of raw_input**

Comment: `question.strip() == 'y'`

Comment: This code works fine (I tested it myself).  Maybe the user is not actually typing in "y" but instead "y ".

Comment: _"If they enter `"y"`, it goes straight to the else condition."_. Do you mean, the user is entering the three characters quote mark, y, and quote mark; and then pressing Enter? Tell your users they only need to type the letter.

Comment: @user2799617 Downvote for improper clain? The formatting was messed up during the copy and paste procedure.

Comment: He probably meant "claim". As in, you claim it doesn't work, but it does.

Comment: @Kevin yeah i was using input instead of raw_input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define start_over...it will work

```
question = raw_input("Do you wish to try again? y/n: ")
start_over = 10
if question == "y":
    start_over -= 1
    print start_over
else:
    raise SystemExit
```