# Python calculator only returning else statement even though the if or elif is true

Tags: if-statement, input, calculator

Here is my code, why does it keep returning the else value even though I am inputting a valid operation?

```
num1 = float(input("Choose a number: "))
op = input("Choose an operation: ")
num2 = float(input("Choose a second number: "))


if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print("Invalid Operator")
```

Comment: The use of `input` might be the problem, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054661/if-input-equals-string-do-something-python-2-7).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if input equals string, do something... python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054661/if-input-equals-string-do-something-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0):

your program seems correct and it produces correct output. Probably, there could be something wrong with your input. Here is an example of input and output by your program.

```
Choose a number: 5
Choose an operation: +
Choose a second number: 3
8.0
```